# WebGL rendering fails when using color buffer

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
<canvas id ="ctx" width = "300" height = "300"></canvas> 
    <script>
        //Getting Webgl Context

        var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx");
        var webgl = ctx.getContext("experimental-webgl");

        /*Creating Shader*/

        //Vertex Code
        var vertexCode =
        'attribute vec3 coordinates;'+
        'attribute vec3 color;'+
        'varying vec3 vColor;'+
        'void main(void) {' +
           ' gl_Position = vec4(coordinates, 1.0);' +
           'vColor = color;'+
        '}';

        //Creating Shader Object    
        var vertexShader = webgl.createShader(webgl.VERTEX_SHADER);

        //Assigning the Source
        webgl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexCode);

        //Compiling the Source
        webgl.compileShader(vertexShader);

        //Fragment Shader Code 
         var fragmentCode ='precision mediump float;'+
        'varying vec3 vColor;'+
        'void main(void) {'+
           'gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.);'+
        '}';

        //Creating Shader Object    
        var fragmentShader = webgl.createShader(webgl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        //Assigning the Source
        webgl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentCode);

        //Compiling the Source
        webgl.compileShader(fragmentShader);

        //Creating Program to store Shader
        var shaderProgram = webgl.createProgram();

        //Attaching the shaders
        webgl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        webgl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);

        //linking the Program
        webgl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

        //using the Program
        webgl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

        //Defining geometry
        var vertices = [
        -0.5,0.5,0.0,
        -0.5,-0.5,0.0,
        0.5,-0.5,0.0,
        0.5,0.5,0.0
     ];

     var colors = [0,0,1, 1,0,0, 0,1,0, 1,0,1,];

     indices = [3,2,1,3,1,0];

        //Creating a Buffer
        var VextexBuffer = webgl.createBuffer();
        var IndexBuffer = webgl.createBuffer();
        var colorBuffer = webgl.createBuffer();

        //Binding the Buffer
        webgl.bindBuffer(webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, VextexBuffer);
        webgl.bindBuffer(webgl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexBuffer);
        webgl.bindBuffer(webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);

        //Buffer Data
        webgl.bufferData(webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), webgl.STATIC_DRAW);
        webgl.bufferData(webgl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), webgl.STATIC_DRAW);
        webgl.bufferData(webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), webgl.STATIC_DRAW);

        /*Associating the shaders to bufferObject*/

        //Getting attribute location
        var coord = webgl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram,"coordinates");
        var color = webgl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "color");

        //pointing an attribute to the currently bound VBO
        webgl.vertexAttribPointer(coord, 3, webgl.FLOAT, false ,0,0);
        webgl.vertexAttribPointer(color, 3, webgl.FLOAT, false ,0,0);

        //enabling the attributes
        webgl.enableVertexAttribArray(coord);
        webgl.enableVertexAttribArray(color);
        //Unbind Array


        /*Drawing the Triangle*/

        //Clearing the Colour
        webgl.clearColor(.5,.5,.5,1);

        //Enabling the depth test
        webgl.enable(webgl.DEPTH_TEST);

        //Clearing colour nuffer bit
        webgl.clear(webgl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        //Setting a viewport
        webgl.viewport(0,0,ctx.width,ctx.height);

        //Draw the triangle
            webgl.drawElements(webgl.TRIANGLES,indices.length,webgl.UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I remove colour buffer and everything related to it, the code runs but with colour buffer, I only see gray canvas, nothing else.

Also Chrome console doesn't show any errors or warnings.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting your vertex positions with your colors:

```
 webgl.bufferData(webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), webgl.STATIC_DRAW);
 webgl.bufferData(webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), webgl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

At any given time there can only be **one** buffer bound for each type (`ARRAY_BUFFER` and  `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`), so
the flow is to bind a buffer and set its data followed by setting up the vertex attribute pointers for **that specific** buffer, then proceed to the next buffer:

```
// setup positions
var VextexBuffer = webgl.createBuffer();
webgl.bindBuffer(webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, VextexBuffer);
webgl.bufferData(webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), webgl.STATIC_DRAW);
var coord = webgl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram,"coordinates");
webgl.vertexAttribPointer(coord, 3, webgl.FLOAT, false ,0,0);

// setup indices
var IndexBuffer = webgl.createBuffer();
webgl.bindBuffer(webgl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexBuffer);
webgl.bufferData(webgl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), webgl.STATIC_DRAW);

// setup colors
var colorBuffer = webgl.createBuffer();
webgl.bindBuffer(webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
webgl.bufferData(webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), webgl.STATIC_DRAW);
var color = webgl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "color");
webgl.vertexAttribPointer(color, 3, webgl.FLOAT, false ,0,0);
```

For applications that work with multiple different buffers and intend to be realtime the flow is to create and set the buffers during initialization phase to then only bind the buffer and set the vertex attribute pointers during the animation loop.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
<canvas id ="ctx" width = "300" height = "300"></canvas> 
    <script>
        //Getting Webgl Context

        var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx");
        var webgl = ctx.getContext("experimental-webgl");

        /*Creating Shader*/

        //Vertex Code
        var vertexCode =
        'attribute vec3 coordinates;'+
        'attribute vec3 color;'+
        'varying vec3 vColor;'+
        'void main(void) {' +
           ' gl_Position = vec4(coordinates, 1.0);' +
           'vColor = color;'+
        '}';

        //Creating Shader Object    
        var vertexShader = webgl.createShader(webgl.VERTEX_SHADER);

        //Assigning the Source
        webgl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexCode);

        //Compiling the Source
        webgl.compileShader(vertexShader);

        //Fragment Shader Code 
         var fragmentCode ='precision mediump float;'+
        'varying vec3 vColor;'+
        'void main(void) {'+
           'gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.);'+
        '}';

        //Creating Shader Object    
        var fragmentShader = webgl.createShader(webgl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        //Assigning the Source
        webgl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentCode);

        //Compiling the Source
        webgl.compileShader(fragmentShader);

        //Creating Program to store Shader
        var shaderProgram = webgl.createProgram();

        //Attaching the shaders
        webgl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        webgl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);

        //linking the Program
        webgl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

        //using the Program
        webgl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

        //Defining geometry
        var vertices = [
        -0.5,0.5,0.0,
        -0.5,-0.5,0.0,
        0.5,-0.5,0.0,
        0.5,0.5,0.0
     ];

     var colors = [0,0,1, 1,0,0, 0,1,0, 1,0,1,];

     indices = [3,2,1,3,1,0];

       // setup positions
       var VextexBuffer = webgl.createBuffer();
       webgl.bindBuffer(webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, VextexBuffer);
       webgl.bufferData(webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), webgl.STATIC_DRAW);
       var coord = webgl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram,"coordinates");
       webgl.vertexAttribPointer(coord, 3, webgl.FLOAT, false ,0,0);

       // setup indices
       var IndexBuffer = webgl.createBuffer();
       webgl.bindBuffer(webgl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexBuffer);
       webgl.bufferData(webgl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), webgl.STATIC_DRAW);

       // setup colors
       var colorBuffer = webgl.createBuffer();
       webgl.bindBuffer(webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
       webgl.bufferData(webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), webgl.STATIC_DRAW);
       var color = webgl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "color");
       webgl.vertexAttribPointer(color, 3, webgl.FLOAT, false ,0,0);

        //enabling the attributes
        webgl.enableVertexAttribArray(coord);
        webgl.enableVertexAttribArray(color);
        //Unbind Array


        /*Drawing the Triangle*/

        //Clearing the Colour
        webgl.clearColor(.5,.5,.5,1);

        //Enabling the depth test
        webgl.enable(webgl.DEPTH_TEST);

        //Clearing colour nuffer bit
        webgl.clear(webgl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        //Setting a viewport
        webgl.viewport(0,0,ctx.width,ctx.height);

        //Draw the triangle
            webgl.drawElements(webgl.TRIANGLES,indices.length,webgl.UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: They say to avoid using comments for saying thanks but i really need to thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3dygLd7r/).

The biggest mistake in your code is the use of the `bindBuffer` method. A WebGL context can bind a buffer at a time. Binding two or more buffers at a time results in binding only the last one.

When you have to copy data to a buffer, you need to bind it and then call `bufferData` function.

Same applies to the `vertexAttribPointer` function. First bind the buffer you want the attribute to bind to, then call `vertexAttribPointer`, and so on with the other buffer.

```js
//Getting Webgl Context

var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx");
var webgl = ctx.getContext("experimental-webgl");

/*Creating Shader*/

//Vertex Code
var vertexCode =
        'attribute vec3 coordinates;' +
        'attribute vec3 color;' +
        'varying vec3 vColor;' +
        'void main(void) {' +
        ' gl_Position = vec4(coordinates, 1.0);' +
        'vColor = color;' +
        '}';

//Creating Shader Object    
var vertexShader = webgl.createShader(webgl.VERTEX_SHADER);

//Assigning the Source
webgl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexCode);

//Compiling the Source
webgl.compileShader(vertexShader);

//Fragment Shader Code 
var fragmentCode = 'precision mediump float;' +
        'varying vec3 vColor;' +
        'void main(void) {' +
        'gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.);' +
        '}';

//Creating Shader Object    
var fragmentShader = webgl.createShader(webgl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

//Assigning the Source
webgl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentCode);

//Compiling the Source
webgl.compileShader(fragmentShader);

//Creating Program to store Shader
var shaderProgram = webgl.createProgram();

//Attaching the shaders
webgl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
webgl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);

//linking the Program
webgl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

//using the Program
webgl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

//Defining geometry
var vertices = [
    -0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
    -0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
    0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
    0.5, 0.5, 0.0
];

var colors = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ];

indices = [3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0];

var coord = webgl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "coordinates");
var color = webgl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "color");

webgl.enableVertexAttribArray(coord);
webgl.enableVertexAttribArray(color);

//Creating a Buffer
var VextexBuffer = webgl.createBuffer();
var IndexBuffer = webgl.createBuffer();
var colorBuffer = webgl.createBuffer();

//Binding the Buffer
webgl.bindBuffer(webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, VextexBuffer);
webgl.bufferData(webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), webgl.STATIC_DRAW);

webgl.bindBuffer(webgl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexBuffer);
webgl.bufferData(webgl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), webgl.STATIC_DRAW);

webgl.bindBuffer(webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
webgl.bufferData(webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), webgl.STATIC_DRAW);

webgl.bindBuffer(webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, VextexBuffer);
webgl.vertexAttribPointer(coord, 3, webgl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

webgl.bindBuffer(webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
webgl.vertexAttribPointer(color, 3, webgl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
/*Drawing the Triangle*/
//Clearing the Colour
webgl.clearColor(.5, .5, .5, 1);
//Enabling the depth test
webgl.enable(webgl.DEPTH_TEST);
//Clearing colour nuffer bit
webgl.clear(webgl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
//Setting a viewport
webgl.viewport(0, 0, ctx.width, ctx.height);
//Draw the triangle
webgl.drawElements(webgl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, webgl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

```html
<canvas id ="ctx" width = "300" height = "300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Please use stackoverflows inbuilt code sample feature to avoid code examples being lost in case jsfiddle(or any other service) goes down or purges older entries.

Comment: I agree with you, still new here in StackOverflow. Edited with snippet

Comment: Thanks you very much.